# Parrot os is not starting

Tags: linux, boot, parrot-os

i want your help to find how can i recover my parrot os system. I use parrot os alongwith windows. I have 4gb of ram so i tried to make a swap file in parrot os . **I created the swap file and put swappiness=10 in system.conf** . But when i tried to reboot. I shows an error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sjBR.jpg)

I tried many times to start it nut i failed.
Here is the error when i try to start it
Reloading system manager configuration Starting default target

***You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked. See sulogin(8) man page for more details.***

**Press Enter to continue**.

When i go to recovery mode it show **failed to load /swap**
image of error recovery error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi6gp.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a Linux live-CD USB stick.
Boot up with live CD, mount your system root path(should be somewhere at /dev/) to /mnt, then you need to check `/etc/fstab` file, remove /swap item inside.

After that follow [Arch - swap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Swap) to set-up swap partition properly.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. this method solved my problem